# What's the phrase for things that get better with age?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the phrase for things that (seem to) get better with age?

For example:
JJ Abrams Star Trek is to TNG as Lucas's prequels were to Star Wars.

Comment: I think you're examples are unclear as there might be some difference of opinion (in both examples) as to which one is better.

Comment: I wholeheartedly concur with Sam here.  Many moviegoers found the _Star Wars_ prequels terrible, especially when compared to the original trilogy.

Comment: :) Thanks guys - I think the person I quoted that from was wishing for the better days of TNG over JJ Abrams. In my view that's not a valid claim, the old TNG episodes just *seem* better. I personally think the JJ Abrams movie is very good, and SW Ep1 very bad.

Comment: @hawkeye: Most/all of the answers so far offer words suitable for describing *something which has in fact improved with age*, but it seems to me your question asks for a term to describe *things which have the potential to improve over time*, not things which have already done this. Can you edit your question text to clarify/emphasise exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: I'd like to think it was 'me'.

Comment: My humble apologies @FumbleFingers - I meant to say "things that do get and have gotten better" which the answers reflect. I'm happy with the answers that have come through. I was hoping there would be a single word for 'potential for nostalgia' - but it looks like that is coming up short.

Comment: @Barrie England: haha - the question is do you want to characterise yourself as *already "well-aged"*, or as having the potential for ageing well at some point in the future? That second one being a quality for which English may not actually have a generic term (you probably don't want to go around telling people you're [cellarable](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1458219)! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things are often said to *improve* with age.

Headline from the March 2nd *USA Today*: "Like a fine wine, brain can improve with age"

If the thing actually does not improve, but the person looking back on it seems to think it is better, that could be considered *nostalgia*.

Answer (score 4):

It could be said that it matures with age.

Answer (score 2):

I think of the word **mellow**. From NOAD:

> **mellow**
>   *adjective*
>   1 (esp. of sound, taste, and color) pleasantly smooth or soft; free from harshness: *she was hypnotized by the mellow tone of his voice* | *slow cooking gives the dish a sweet, mellow flavor.*
>   2 (of a person's character) softened or matured by age or experience: *a more mellow personality.*

It can also be used as a verb, meaning to become mellow.

Comment: Some things indeed improve as they mellow with age.  With the science fiction genre, though, the word _mellow_ may not imply _improvement_.  Case in point: _Star Wars_ mellowed, but didn't improve - at least in the minds of some critics.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about things *seeming* to get better with age, that would be **nostalgia**.  As for things actually getting better with age, that's just my wishful thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Using a *wine* simile to describe things that get better with age is not uncommon.

In fact, I did an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wine%20improves%20with%20age&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=6) on "*wine improves with age*," and found more than one reference that wasn't talking about what happens in the wine cellar:

> "*A trader with a good mind, like good wine, improves with age*."
>
> "*He is a clear example of a man who, like a good wine, improves with
>   age*."
>
> "*She is a music maestro who like wine, improves with age*."
>
> "*Friendship, like good wine, improves with age*..."
>
> "*Good judgment... like a fine wine, improves with age*."
>
> "*For better or worse, the comparative study of literature, like fine wine, improves with age.*"
>
> "*Widely known in its initial versions as the first authoring system
>   for the Apple II, Tutor-Tech Hypermedia Toolkit, like fine wine,
>   improves with age*."
>
> "*High-quality sex, like good wine, improves with age*."

On second thought, maybe that last example *does* refer to what happens in the wine cellar...

Answer (score 2):

- Seasoned, to become seasoned with the passage of time
- Mature e.g. "she had matured from adolescence into the full blossom of womanhood"
- Gentrified: That means something that was old, then improved, so it is a marginally valid answer. But "gentrified" ***is*** a phrase for something that got better with age (although it probably got worse before it got better)!
- To be a classic e.g. "an enduring classic, having withstood the test of time"
- Been around the block
- Antique
- Vintage

Some are euphemisms, I think. And most are ***definitely*** cliches!

Answer (score 1):

The “[Lindy effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindy_effect)” describes things where the mortality rate decreases over time; the longer they’ve been around, the longer they’ll last. It’s sometimes extended to imply quality, not just longevity. Some people (e.g. in certain Twitter circles) have begun using “Lindy” as an adjective, like “the movie, like wine, seems to be Lindy.” I think it’s almost exactly what you’re looking for, but it’s currently *extremely* niche and idiosyncratic and too connotative of certain social circles.

Comment: Finally, an explanation of the term!  True confession: NNT follows me on the Twitter but I didn't understand the meaning until now, Thank you!